# Unable to create BLOB/Binary types with LoopBack 4

Tags: mysql, binary, blob, loopbackjs, loopback4

I'm trying to use [Loopback](https://loopback.io/) for my new projects, but I've been facing some problems...

I have the habit of storing my UUIDs ID in a binary format at my databases, here's an example:

```js
@model({
  settings: { mysql: { table: 'application' } },
})
export class Application extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'buffer',
    required: true,
    generated: false,
    id: true,
    dataLength: 16,
  })
  id: BinaryType;
 [...]
}
```

But when I try to do the `migration`, I've been receiving that error from `mysql`:

```sh
"BLOB/TEXT column 'id' used in key specification without a key length"
```

I really tried everything and nothing works. Hope that you'll be able to help me!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll show the answer for this question that I made.

Just define your `model` with the following info:

```js
  @property({
    required: true,
    mysql: {
      columnName: 'application_id',
      dataType: 'VARBINARY',
      dataLength: 16,
      nullable: 'NO'
    }
  })
  application_id: string;
```

It worked like a charm for me :)

Thank you all!